# Java android snackbar display cover view

Tags: java, android, android-snackbar

On my view I have a google map and when I clicked on marker I want to display a snackbar, Now I display a snackBar but this snackbar cover my google maps

This is what I do:

```
public void mySnackbar(PGO pgo,View view) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams objLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
    layout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View snackView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_snackbar, null);
    Button textViewOne = (Button) snackView.findViewById(R.id.txtOne);
    TextView tvName = (TextView) snackView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    tvName.setText(pgo.getFull());
    textViewOne.setText("Potwierdź");
    textViewOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("One", "First one is clicked");
            snackbar.dismiss();
        }
    });

    Button textViewTwo = (Button) snackView.findViewById(R.id.txtTwo);
    textViewTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("Two", "Second one is clicked");
            snackbar.dismiss();

        }
    });


      gMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                for(PGO pgo : pgoList.pgos){
                    if(pgo.getFull().equalsIgnoreCase(marker.getTitle())){
                        currentPGO = pgo;
                        View view = findViewById(R.id.map);
//                        mySnackbar(pgo,getWindow().getDecorView());
                        mySnackbar(pgo,view);
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I want to display a snackBar and steal show whole google maps , I want to displey snackbar under a google maps

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `steal show`? . `SnackBar` is a Overlay View . If you want to display it under map you need to have a view in layout and make it visible on Marker click .

Comment: @ADM how I can do this ?

Comment: @ADM What if  a custom snackbar with a custom layout and duration of few seconds is displayed ?

Comment: custom snackbar will also show overlay . I think Question is not about overlay . OP is asking to show it under map .

Comment: @ADM but can I display a snack bar under a map  or can I sen margin botton on map ?

Comment: For this you will need to calculate exact height of `SnackBar` first . Don't make it complicated just have a view align bottom, of screen and make visible with animation (if required).